# using microsoft graph api to read mail behalf of users in the enterprise

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I am trying to get the messages inside the mailbox of users in the enterprise via the admin account.

In my app I have the following permissions:

[image: Microsoft Graph Application Permissions]

I used the `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/adminconsent?...` to grant the application permissions to read mail in all mailboxes and after that, I used the OAuth2 authentication to get a Bearer token.

This is the response I got from the token endpoint:

```
{
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "scope": "Mail.Read User.Read User.Read.All profile openid email",
  "access_token": "<token>",
  "expires_in": 3599,
  "ext_expires_in": 3599
}
```

When I used this to access a mailbox via `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/USER-ID/messages`, I got the following response

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ErrorAccessDenied",
    "message": "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "a31bcf73-4bd6-4fed-bfee-d70328e0703e",
      "date": "2018-11-26T15:20:37"
    }
  }
}
```

However, when I use this endpoint with the User ID of the authenticated admin account, I am able to access the messages in that mailbox.

But I would like to access the mailboxes of *all users* in the organization via Microsoft Graph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Outlook endpoints operate a little differently than most of the Graph endpoints, rather than having a `.all` variation of their scopes (i.e. `user.read` vs `user.read.all`), it depends on which scope type (Delegated vs. Application) is being used.

When Delegated scopes are being used, `Mail.Read` only provides access to the authenticated user's mailbox (the only exception being those that have been *explicitly shared* with that user).

When Application scopes are being used, `Mail.Read` provides access to any user's mailbox.

Now, this is where things get a little wonky, *the type of scope that gets applied is entirely dependant on the OAuth Grant used to obtain the token*.

- When using Implicit or Authorization Code grants, Delegated scopes are applied.
- When using the Client Credentials grant, Application scopes are applied.

So in order for you to access any user's mailbox via `/v1.0/users/{someUser}/messages`, you first need to obtain your token using the Client Credentials OAuth grant. You can find a walkthrough on how this works in the documentation under ["Get access without a user"](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service).

Comment: Thank you that's solved it, one more issue I have missed when I made a call to the token I used the https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token' URL while I should have use https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant returned from admin consent}/oauth2/v2.0/token

Comment: That's correct. Since you're authenticating the app rather than an email address, it isn't possible for AAD to automatically discover which tenant it should authenticate against (a single app id can be authed by multiple tenants). You need to include the specific tenant id rather than `common`. One aside, it doesn't have to be the GUID, it can be the primary domain as well (`/tenant.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token`).

Comment: I am getting forbidden error, while getting a email using graph api, is Global admin access necassary for calling it? Also, what application permission and delegated permissions should be granted to app, if i am calling api from simple html page.

Comment: I am trying to get the emails from mail box. I have api permissions as application. 
I generated client token with grant type = client_credentials. But when hitting graph APIs with generated token I am getting below error:
Current authenticated context is not valid for this request. This occurs when a request is made to an endpoint that requires user sign-in. For example, /me requires a signed-in user.  Acquire a token on behalf of a user to make requests to these endpoints.  Use the OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow for mobile and native apps and the OAuth 2.0 implicit flow