# MS Graph Mail The specified object was not found in the store

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-web-addins

I am trying to retrive information about mails within a users mailbox.
I am using the following snippet of code:

```
graphClient.Users[mailbox]
  .Messages[messageId]
  .Request()
  .GetAsync()
  .Result;
```

Which works fine for the most requests.
The messageId is read previously from the graph API.
The app registration has the following permissions.
[image: App registration permissions]

Found this: [using microsoft graph api to read mail behalf of users in the enterprise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53484484/using-microsoft-graph-api-to-read-mail-behalf-of-users-in-the-enterprise) -> I'm using the application login method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

MessageId's change when an item is moved between folders so it most likely that is the reason your having the problem. To solve it use the immutableid https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-immutable-id